# Java Card client-server Shareable interface returns 6F00

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard

I've tried to create a simple Client and Server applets in java card 2.2.2 using Eclipse 3.7 SDK using the Shareable Interfaces. When the method `JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject` is called it throws an exception and so the return SW sets to 6F00.

This is the Client app code (`Test_Client.java`):

```
    package client;

import server.Test_ServerInf;
import javacard.framework.AID;
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;

public class Test_Client extends Applet {

    protected static final byte INS1 = (byte)0xE2;
    protected static final byte INS2 = (byte)0x21;

    byte[] ServerAIDbyte={(byte)0x20,(byte)0x21,(byte)0x22,(byte)0x23,(byte)0x24,(byte)0x25,(byte)0x26,(byte)0x27,(byte)0x01};
    AID ServerAID;

    private Test_Client() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new Test_Client().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] apduBuffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        byte Ins=apduBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];
        short byteread = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();

        if (selectingApplet())
            return;

        switch (Ins){
        case INS1:
            Ins1_Handler(apdu);
            return;
        case INS2:
            Ins2_Handler(apdu,apduBuffer);
            return;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_FUNC_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }
    private void Ins1_Handler(APDU apdu){
        Test_ServerInf sio = null;
        ServerAID=JCSystem.lookupAID(ServerAIDbyte,(short) 0,(byte) ServerAIDbyte.length);
        if(ServerAID==null)
            ISOException.throwIt( (short) 0x6A82);
        ////server request
        try{
        sio=(Test_ServerInf)(JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(ServerAID, (byte) 0));
        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
       {
           ISOException.throwIt((short)0x12);
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           ISOException.throwIt((short)0x10);
       }
        if(sio==null)
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6A00);

    }

    private void Ins2_Handler(APDU apdu,byte[] apduBuffer){
            Test_ServerInf sio = null;
           ////connect to server  
          ServerAID=JCSystem.lookupAID(ServerAIDbyte,(short) 0,(byte) ServerAIDbyte.length);
           if(ServerAID==null)
                ISOException.throwIt( (short) 0x6A82);
           ////server request
           try{
               sio=(Test_ServerInf)(JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(ServerAID, (byte) 0));
           }
           catch(SecurityException e)
           {
               ISOException.throwIt((short)0x12);
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               ISOException.throwIt((short)0x10);
           }
           if(sio==null)
                ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6A00); 
    }


}
```

And this is Server applet code (`Test_Server.java`):

```
  package server;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import server.Test_ServerInf;
import javacard.framework.Shareable;
import javacard.framework.AID;

public class Test_Server extends Applet implements Test_ServerInf{


    private Test_Server() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new Test_Server().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Shareable getShareableInterfaceObject(AID clientAID, byte parameter) {
        return this;
    }

    public short method1(){
        return (short)0x01;
    }
    public short method2(){
        return (short)0x02;
    }

}
```

and the shareable interface file (`Test_ServerInf.java`):

```
package server;

import javacard.framework.Shareable;

public interface Test_ServerInf extends Shareable {

    public short method1();
    public short method2();

}
```

Comment: So is the exception caught by the `catch` for `Ins2_Handler`? If so, have you tried to print out the reason? Note that it is particularly hard for us to "debug" online, we don't even know how and if you've instantiated the server and such.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes that's an exception but its the `RuntimeException` not the `CardRuntimeException` so it doesn't contain any method except `equals()`. I've instantiated the server and client both. the only exception that `JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject` throws is `SecurityException`.

Comment: Did you try and remove the cast? I can only see one other possible exception that's possible given the official JC API at that location.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes, it throws that exception again, however removing the cast causes not be able to use the interface's internal methods.

Comment: Vexing. Can you separately catch `SecurityException` before `Exception`? It doesn't have a reason code either, so we at least know which exception is thrown (yeah, I know, it is the only one that *should* be thrown, but...).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, I've done it. The result is that the `SecurityException` is thrown

Comment: How are you instantiating the applets? Are they using the same domain / 5 byte RID? I think it is time to look beyond the code. I presume they are compiled for the same runtime target? Could you try and specifying `Test_ServerInf` instead of the `Shareable` return type?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes they are using the same domain. I didn't get that how can I determine that they are using the same runtime target. Specifying `Test_ServerInf` instead of `Shareable` causes error `the return type is incompatible with Applet.getShareableInterfaceObject`

Comment: OK, was worth a try. I think I was mistaken this for generified return types in Java SE. I'm out of ideas (and a bit out of practice w.r.t. `Shareable`).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks a lot. I've tried to make their domain different / different RIDs but nothing changed. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Hmm, I still find that a strange compiler error though, I did some testing in Java SE and an overridden method *can* return an interface if it extends another interface. I'm personally not ruling out a complication / class conversion issue.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes may be that's the point. I have to check another version of Eclipse of another IDE like NetBeans to compile the code. It might be helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of this error. I used to load and install applets using an internally developed application instead of GPShell. When I tried to load and install applets using GPShell the problem solved and everything is ok. I don't know how that application compromises the loaded package but it works fine right know (After 2 weeks of debugging).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to store a reference to the shareable interface object in a member field of your client applet class:

```
sio = (Test_ServerInf)(JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(ServerAID, (byte) 0));
```

where `sio` is defined as private member of the applet class instance:

```
public class Test_Client extends Applet {
    private Test_ServerInf sio;
```

This will result in a `SecurityException` since the shareable interface object is owned by the server applet (i.e. by a different context). You are not allowed to store objects owned by other contexts in an instance field.

See *Accessing Class Instance Object Fields (Section 6.2.8.3)*, in *Runtime Environment Specification, Java Card Platform, Version 2.2.2*:

> Bytecodes: `getfield`, `putfield`
>
> - [...] if the object is owned by an applet in the currently active context, access is allowed.
> - Otherwise, access is denied.

Comment: D'oh, I already said I was rusty in the comments below the answer. Fortunately you weren't :) Makes sense as well, that storing a reference permanently is not allowed. What would you do if the other applet gets deleted for one, it would play merry hell with the GC.

Comment: I've update the source code above considering your note but it throws exception like the previous code.

Comment: @1chenar I'm out of ideas then :-(

Comment: @1chenar You did not make your server applet a default-selected applet, right? And you are doing your tests on the basic logical channel, right?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Yes.